# Converter para String número com formato cientifico

Tags: java

Tenho o seguinte número, em notação cientifica: 7.89894691515E12

Preciso converte-lo para String, no formato comum: 7898946915150

Como fazer isso através do Java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("###.#####");  

String f = formatter.format(d);
```

Você pode explorar a classe `NumberFormat` para mais detalhes